# rsync ntfs/ext4 (windows/synology diskstation) incremental backup

Tags: backup, nas, rsync, synology, incremental-backup

Im trying to incrementel backup my windows server via rsync from my synology nas.
For that i mounted the windows server on my diskstation under `/volume1/homes/multimedia`

Then running rsync: `rsync -av --ignore-existing --size-only --modify-window=10 --progress /volume1/homes/multimedia /volume1/data`

Rsync does not compare anything, it just starts to copy everything again. And not only the modified/new files. Even if the files are exists on the diskstation.

Can some one eplain to my why ? With `--ignore-existing` it should only copy new files or what im missing ?

What is the best way to incrementel backup the windows server via rsync on my diskstation ? And why does it not work this way ?

Comment: Add option `-i` (`--itemize-changes`) to see why rsync wants to send a file. You may need `--modify-window=3602` (something to do with DST daylight saving time differences between Unix and microsoft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `--ignore-existing` unless you really understand that you have a use-case that requires it (mostly it's not needed)
2. Remove `--size-only` entirely so that `rsync` can check file modification times too
3. Remove `--modify-window` unless you are copying from a FAT filesystem

This will give you the simpler and more effective

```
rsync -av /volume1/homes/multimedia/ /volume1/data
```

However, what is even better is for you to install something like `rsyncd` on your Windows Server. (Or `sshd` that can handle an implementation of `rsync`.) Then you can really make good use of `rsync` with its delta copies (only copy the parts of files that have changed):

```
rsync -av --partial user@windowsServer::multimedia/ /volume1/data
```

If that's not possible install the `ssh` and `rsync` client parts on your Windows Server and push the files up to the Synology (this particular local-part syntax is for Cygwin)

```
rsync -av --partial /cygdrive/C/path/to/multimedia/ user@synology:/volume1/data
```

Comment: Thank you. The main issue was the missung  trailing slash on the source :/ so it created a new folder under the target.